# Redirect delay with react-router while running app in iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, react-router

I'm working on embedding my react application into another service with iframe. The application is pretty large and has complex interface and business logic. The problem is that while I run it in chrome tab as always, it works well, but when I run it in iframe and do the same actions, which involves programmatical redirects, it work much-much slower. Like the redirects get some delay. 
I've tried to find any mentions of that problem in google, but it didn't help.

Could anyone tell, what could be the reason of that behavior, or maybe, at least, what direction should I look to?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, but if you could provide some more information about how you're doing the iframe and what's running the iframe, etc? I would edit the question to add more to get a better chance of someone being able to provide an answer.